# Extending a class at runtime

Tags: java, class, runtime, extend

I need to create a custom table UI.  For future flexibility I would rather extend whatever object is returned by the call to `UIManager.getUI()` at the end of `JTable.updateUI()`.  So, I can't know what the class is called, or its path, until runtime.

Is this possible and how would I do it?  I've never done anything to do with reflection, so if it involves that, please be gentle with me :-)  I've had a look at other similar questions here and none of them seem to be what I need, or in an understandable way.  Sorry if I've missed something :-)

Edit: the structure I assume I'll need to use is something along these lines (this will go in my `JTable` descendant):

```
@Override
public void updateUI()
{
  super.updateUI();
  ComponentUI theUI = UIManager.getUI(this)[extended in some way with an overriding paint(){....}]
  setUI((TableUI)theUI);
}
```

It's the syntax for the part in square brackets that I'm missing.  What's in my mind is something kind of like the anonymous inner class declaration, perhaps:

```
...
ComponentUI theUI = UIManager.getUI(this)
{
  public void paint(Graphics g, JComponent c)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm not saying the above exists, but is there some way to achieve it?

Comment: Class.forName("some.path")

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand.  I've edited my original post to show the structure I'm assuming the code will need to use.  I don't see how to use your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is what you meant:

you can load a class at runtime using Class.forName.
example:
say we have an interface A which defines functiong foo() with many classes implementing it. It's important to have same constructor for all of the classes (can do without it but it will be much complicated logic)

at runtime we get the name and possibly path (or we already know where our class should be by some other mean) of the class we want to use. so we can go like this:

```
String class = getPath();
Class<?> toUse = Class.forName(class);
A instance = (A) toUse.getConstructors()[0].newInstance(args);
instance.foo(); //TADA
```

after op edit:
ok your question is more clear now and I doubt my solution is what you're looking for. You can maybe create a class that will compose ComponentUI and use it to extend whatever you need.

something like this (really not sure if it helps since I have no knowledge about this whole JPanel etc thought this question was a mroe general one at first):

```
class B { //maybe class should extend or implement something, depends on what exactly is required
       private ComponentUI c;
       //other fields

       public B(ComponentUI c) {
           this.c = c;
           //other stuff you need done
       }

       //other methods you might need
}
```

Comment: How do I compose ComponentUI?  What does this mean?

Comment: Huge thanks, after much wailing and gnashing of teeth caused by the behind-the-scenes Java code, this worked!!!  I will remember this structure for the future.

Comment: Actually after further thought, I don't think this helps in this particular case.  The problem is that in wrapping a UI inside a UI, I am duplicating all of the mouse handlers, focus handlers, key handlers etc.  This is bound to cause problems in the future.  I've undone your Answer flag, sorry; does anyone have an answer to my original question?  I really think that is the way I'm going to have to do it -- i.e. a single object, which I extend at runtime.  Is this possible?

Comment: You can just delegate the calls in your class to the UI field... No harm should be caused.

Comment: Well -- in explaining to you why I couldn't do as you suggest, I realised that what I need to do is override `BasicTableUI.installListeners()` in my wrapper class, so that it does nothing.  No duplication of listeners :-)  Thanks once again